# "Error: Unresolved external symbol" whenever I use a pure virtual function

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, virtual-functions

I feel like I'm doing something incredibly stupid, but I simply can't figure out what's wrong with my code.  I even made a super simplified version of the code and the error still occurs:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class c1{
public:
    c1(){}
    ~c1(){}

    virtual int add(int a, int b);

private:
protected:


};

class c2 : c1{
public:
    c2(){}
    ~c2(){}

    int add(int a, int b){
        return a+b;
    }

};

int main(){

    c2 c;
    c.add(5,6);

}
```

Can anyone spot what I'm sure is the silliest error of all time?

Here's the exact error message:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall c1::add(int,int)" (?add@c1@@UAEHHH@Z)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
virtual int add(int a, int b);
```

This is not a declaration of a pure virtual function. It's just a declaration of a virtual function. It lacks a definition, which is why you get the error.

```
virtual int add(int a, int b) = 0;
```

This is a declaration of a pure virtual function. It does not require a definition, which is why won't get the error.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting linker error, because `c1::add(int,int)` is not implemented.
either make it pure virtual or implement it.

Answer (score 2):

`c1::add()` is not pure virtual, it's just not implemented. This means the linker is correct to look for a body, and correct to complain when it can't find one. You probably meant this:

```
class c1{
public:
    c1(){}
    ~c1(){}

    virtual int add(int a, int b) = 0;  // adding = 0 makes the function pure virtual

private:
protected:


};
```

Answer (score 1):

c1.add is not pure virtual, you must add **= 0**.

```
virtual int add(int a, int b) = 0;
```

Comment: There is no reason why he would **have** to use public inheritance, unless he wants to downcast pointers to `c2` to `c1*`, which he doesn't do in his example. He can still call `c2::add` from his main, since it is a public function.

Comment: You are very welcome. I'm glad to see you fixed it so soon. :)

Answer (score 1):

change virtual int add(int a, int b);
to 
virtual int add(int a, int b) = 0;

Answer (score 1):

`virtual int add(int a, int b);`
This means "my function `add` can be subclassed". In other to be "my function `add` can be subclassed and is pure virtual" you need

```
virtual int add(int a, int b) = 0;
```